# RichFaces Calendar: Month and Year only display

Tags: calendar, richfaces

I am using Richfaces4.0; need to display selection of month and year only; user chooses it.

```
<rich:calendar id="start" value="#{reportBean.fromDate}" oncurrentdateselect="alert('Hello');" popup="false" showWeekDaysBar="false"  showFooter="false" styleClass="special"></rich:calendar>
```

Script being used as given below, to hide the date grid:

```
.special tr[id] {
  display:none;
}
```

I am following example on the forum, but the selected month/year is not being reflected in the reportBean.fromDate: http://relation.to/12480.lace; I see it does not support oncurrentdateselected attribute.

I am sure missing an important step, please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Value attribute is removed and added with currentDate: